# Command works independently, but not as SSH callback

Tags: mysql, ssh, alias, bashrc

A MySQL cloud server only allows remote access to a certain server (in this example, 11.22.33.44).  Running the following commands from the terminal is verified to work:

1. `ssh -p 40000 user@11.22.33.44`
2. `mysql -u dbuser -p -h example.com`

But when combining them into command (in order to assign it to an alias), it doesn't work:

`ssh -p 40000 user@11.22.33.44 "mysql -u dbuser -p -h example.com"`

No error message is displayed, and the terminal never outputs a returned response.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a "-t" to your ssh command (as in ssh -t -p 40000).  That lets SSH interpret TTY commands like "stop echo for typing in the password", etc.